# Swipe Gesture gives NSException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

i am new to swift programming. So i was trying to add swipe gestures to my application for iOS. But when i try to swipe it stops app and says NSException caught. Here is the code, i have written.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textLabels.append(label0)
    textLabels.append(label1)
    textLabels.append(label2)
    textLabels.append(label3)
    textLabels.append(label4)
    textLabels.append(label5)
    textLabels.append(label6)
    textLabels.append(label7)
    textLabels.append(label8)
    textLabels.append(label9)
    textLabels.append(label10)
    textLabels.append(label11)
    textLabels.append(label12)
    textLabels.append(label13)
    textLabels.append(label14)
    textLabels.append(label15)

    setupInitial()
    print(textLabels.count)
    var request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8950283126375215/1694851281"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(request)
    createAndLoadInterstitial()


    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("gesture:")))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("gesture:")))
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    //setView(view: hideView, hidden: false)

}

func gesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            print("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
            print("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("Swiped left")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
            print("Swiped up")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to my viewController class like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

but it did not work. I also added UIGestureRecognizer. Please help me, i am really stuck here. I am using Xcode 8 and OSX El Capitan. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exception it throws?

Comment: @Bienemann thank you for your response but my problem is solved by the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stringly-typed `Selector()` has been deprecated for the new `#selector()`.

Update your action to `#selector(gesture(gesture:))` and that should fix it

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gesture(gesture:)))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```